# How do I run a python script using pypy on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pypy

When I replaced `!python` with `!pypy` I got an error saying that it is missing the module `scipy`, but it is obviously installed already as I have checked and reinstalled several times. I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: I'm not sure but `pypy` may need own modules, not modules installed for `python`. I don't know if it works but you may have to install it with `pypy -m pip install ...`

Comment: I tried it myself and it prompted me with ```invalid syntax``` error pointed at ```pip``` in the command.

Comment: you could show full error message in question. I tried it only in Linux on local computer and  `pypy3 -m pip install ...` works for me - but `pypy` (which works as Python 2) has blocked `pip` for security reason. But `pypy3` installs in the same folder as `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: I checked in Colab `!python -V` and `!pypy -V` - first runs `python 3.7.10` but second uses `python 2.7` so you may have to install modules with `!pip2` or `!python2 -m pip` to get it in `pypy`. I tried to install `!apt install pypy3` but it doesn't have it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understood what you said, but I tried ```!pip2 install scipy``` and it said that the requirement is already satisfied. When I ran the script using ```!pypy```, it still says it's missing the module.